# my function isn't returning anything in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, printing, nested

I made a function definition for a game I am working for in computer science class.

```
 def bidf(bid): #this card is going to repeat until they give a valid bid
     bid=float(input("What is your bid? "))
     if bid>pot:
         print("Invalid bid: You can't bid more than what is in the pot")
         bidf()
     elif bid>value:
         print("Invalid bid: You don't have that much")
         bidf()
     elif bid<0:
         print("You can not bid negative money")
         bidf()
     else:
         return float(bid)
```

and everytime I try to use the bid variable it doesn't work
For instance this code is where it always crashes

```
if g=="y":
      bidf()
      if card(insidecard[0])==card(outsidecard[0]):
           z=input("Will the next card be higher or lower than the pair?(h/l): ")
           if card(insidecard[0])==14 and card(hand[0])==14:
                print("You quadruple your bid and lose $",bid)
                bid=bid*4
                value=value-bid
                pot=pot+bid
```

What I am trying to do is get bid to show up in the print statement, and the bid to be used to do math to other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `bidf()` in your code, you need to store the return value. So do something like:

```
if g=="y":
    bid = bidf()
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace all of your calls to `bidf()` with `return bidf()`.

Comment: thanks, that helped. Didn't know what I was thinking now that I look at it.